Shadcn UI Sidebar integrated with React
I am having trouble on how to integrate the Shadcn UI sidebar on React because on the official documentation, the examples are on typescript (Next.js?) and I am not familiar with Next.js framework as I am currently learning React. Can anyone help me integrate it with my react app? Assuming that I have this layout:
App.jsx
import "./App.css";
import LandingPage from "./pages/LandingPage";


function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <LandingPage />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;

Main.jsx
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";
import App from "./App.jsx";
import AdminPermits from "./pages/AdminPermits.jsx";
import DormerHomepage from "./pages/DormerHomepage.jsx";
import TransientView from "./pages/TransientView.jsx";
import TransientSuccess from "./pages/TransientSuccess.jsx";
import TransientBooking from "./pages/TransientBooking.jsx";
import LoginPage from "./pages/Login.jsx";
import TestDormPage from "./pages/TestDormerPage.jsx";
import ManageDormers from "./pages/ManageDormers.jsx";
import ManageRooms from "./pages/ManageRooms.jsx";

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <App />,
  },
  {
    path: "/manage",
    element: <AdminPermits />,
  },
  {
    path: "/dormer",
    element: <DormerHomepage />,
  },
  {
    path: "/transient",
    element: <TransientView />,
  },
  {
    path: "/transient-success",
    element: <TransientSuccess />,
  },
  {
    path: "/transient-booking",
    element: <TransientBooking />,
  },
  {
    path: "/login",
    element: <LoginPage />,
  },
  {
    path: "/testDormer",
    element: <TestDormPage />,
  },
  {
    path: "/manage-dormers",
    element: <ManageDormers/>
  },
  {
    path: "/manage-rooms",
    element: <ManageRooms/>
  }
]);

createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <RouterProvider router={router} />
);

Note: I only want to integrate the sidebar on pages like manage-rooms and manage-dormers

The shadcn/ui is just a collection of premade components so that you can reuse them in your own application meaning using them in Next.js or React.js shouldn't really matter.
If you only want to put them in certain pages, then just edit those components to contain the code provided in the documentation: https://ui.shadcn.com/docs/components/sidebar#:~:text=the%20Sidebar.-,Usage,-app/layout.tsx
<SidebarProvider>
  <AppSidebar />
  <main>
    <SidebarTrigger />
    {CONTENT_HERE}
  </main>
</SidebarProvider>

Or what you could also do is provide them directly in the router!
{
  path: "/manage-dormers",
  element: <SidebarProvider>
      <AppSidebar />
      <main>
        <SidebarTrigger />
        <ManageDormers />
      </main>
    </SidebarProvider>},
{
  path: "/manage-rooms",
  element: <SidebarProvider>
             <AppSidebar />
             <main>
               <SidebarTrigger />
               <ManageRooms />
             </main>
         </SidebarProvider>
}

But this approach might ruin your styling in those pages.

Thank you so much for this kind samaritan
